# Is it possible to get all user id's who have shared a specific post, through graph api or any other resource?

Tags: facebook, post, share

I am looking for a way to record user id's of a public post for a brand. If there are any resources available, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving share data with FB API doesn't seem to be officialy supported by Facebook, but you can retrieve posts shares with [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), just do the following:

- Get the ID of your post (eg. /me/posts query)
- Split the ID on underscore character and get the second part (first part indentifies posts author)
- Query the shares: [id_2nd_part]/sharedposts

Note that since it's not officialy supported it may stop working at some point in the future

You can test it with [Graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) - to get shared posts you need read_stream permissions on your access token if I'm not mistaken

Comment: The first part of the ID identifies the wall on which the post appears, not necessarily the post's author.